# Were there any Death Note Rules not shown mid episode of the anime?

Tags: death-note

In the anime when there is a break in the episode we have scenes that look similar to the "How to Use" pages of the manga. except they aren't titled like "How to Use XVI".

I am wondering, are there any rules that were in the "How to Use" Pages that were not shown in the middle of the episodes? if so which ones?

Comment: I think you can go through the manga to make sure all the rules are covered in the anime. But if you are interested in only knowing the rules, [here](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note) is a link to it. I think the page also has a fake rules page. Maybe you check that out also. Kudos